# How to get the local time correctly in Functions after the change in Firebase 5.4.1?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

After the change in the new version of Firebase 5.4.1. for web, when I send a timestamp like

const timestamp = {seconds: 1534183200, nanoseconds: 0}

to the server in my Functions, I can't convert it to local time that the client is in as timestamp has 0 timeZoneOffset. Do I need to keep track of timezones per client now or is there a way that I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Timestamps don't have timezones.  They just measure on offset from unix epoch time (since Jan 1, 1970).

If you want a timezone, you should get that from the user's device, or ask them for their preference.  Then you can use that to format the timestamp to their locale.  This is typically done on the client app, not on the backend.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I understand why we use timestamps but say I need to do some calculation on the time which needs to be in the correct local time of the user for the result to make sense, then what? Would I need the offset? Is there a way to save it to Firebase in localtime of user?

Comment: Time calculations using timestamps or other time measurements involving only integer offsets should never need to involve timezone.  You only need timezone when it comes time to render a date on screen to the user.

Comment: Correct, the calculation is not as simple as a date conversion. Imagine a calendar that multiple events can overlap. For keeping track of overlapping events per each time slot I have an array of time slots that can increment or decrement per event. Now, if I don't have the hours of events in local time on server, wrong time slots get incremented/decremented. Anyways, I'll figure out a way. Thanks again.

Comment: @TheeBen Have you ever figured out a way to do it?